# @requestParam in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, datatables-1.10

My AJAX request sends this as Payload.

```
data[0][id]: 
data[0][name]: asdfasd
data[0][betrag]: tzutz
data[0][budgetTyp]: tzutz
data[0][kommentar]: tzu
data[0][vq0]: 
data[0][vq1]: 
data[0][vq2]: 
data[0][vq3]: 
data[0][vq4]: 
action: create
pid: 2000382
```

I want to recive this as a @RequestParam in a Rest method, somehting like

```
@PostMapping("/plan")
public OutputDtPlan editDataPlan(@RequestParam inputDt dPlan) {
    // so i can then work with  
    dPlan.data...
    dPlan.action... and so on

}
```

i how does my inputDt class

```
public class inputDt {
    private Map<String,Map<String, String>> data; <---- instead of this i woul like 
    //private Plan p; 
    private String action;
    private Long pid
```

is this possible?

Comment: `@RequestParam` is for individual parameters (like `action` in this case). What you want is `@ModelAttribute` to bind the attributes.

Comment: If you want to bind the data array/list to something you need to create an object that has the `id`, `name` etc. attributes and put that as a list in your `inputDt` (I would recommend general naming practices and use `InputDT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam` is used to get query string parameters from URL. In case of `@PostMapping` better to use `@RequestBody` and parse your data inside body.

Comment: He wants to bind request parameters one needs to use `@ModelAttribute` then, the `@RequestBody` is for json/xml (de)serializing (or other transports) but not for binding form attributes.

Comment: Yes, in the point of binding, better to use `@ModelAttribute`. But In case of union this data into single object, he can use `@RequestBody`.

Comment: No you don't, it depends on what you are sending. When sending JSON (or xml or what ever is supported with the `HttpMessageConverter`) you need to use `@RequestBody`, when bindong you need `@ModelAttribute`. It depends on how/what you are sending, it has nothing to do with parameters or binding to an object.